# bash set environment variable before command in script

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, environment-variables, gnu-make

I compile my project with:

`debug=yes make -j4` or `debug=no make -j4`

The debug variable changes some compiler flags in the Makefile

Instead of typing this repeatedly in the shell, I wrote this script (lets call it `daemon`):

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -q -m -e close_write `ls *.c* *.h*` |
while read; do
    make -j4
done
```

so I just do `./daemon` which automatically builds whenever a file is written to.

However, I would like to be able to pass the `debug=no make -j4` to the `./daemon` script like this:

`./daemon debug=no make -j4`

So I modified the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage `basename $0` [COMMAND]"
    exit 1;
fi
inotifywait -q -m -e close_write `ls *.c* *.h*` |
while read; do
    "$@"
done
```

This works with `./daemon make -j4` but when I say `daemon debug=no make -j4` I get the following error:

> ./daemon: line 9: debug=no: command not found

How can I make it so `debug=no` is recognized as a variable and not a command in the `daemon` script?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `ls` like that; just use the glob directly, as `inotifywait -q -m -e close_write *.c* *.h* | ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion of `"$@"` is parsed *after* any pre-command assignments are recognized. All you need to do is ensure that `debug=...` is in the environment of the command that runs `make`, which is your `daemon` script.

```
debug=no ./daemon make -j4
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable expansions will only ever become arguments (including the zeroth argument: the command name).

They will never become:

- Redirections, so you can't `var='> file'; cmd $var`
- Shell keywords or operators, so you can't `var='&'; mydaemon $var`
- Assignments, including prefix assignments, so you can't `var='debug=yes'; $var make` as you discovered
- Command expansions, loops, process substitutions, `&&/||`, escape sequences, or anything else.

If you want to do this though, you're in luck: there's a standard POSIX tool that will turn leading `key=value` pairs into environment variables and run the program you want.

It's called `env`. Here's an example:

```
run() {
  env "$@"
}

run debug=yes make -j 4
```

Though TBH I'd use [chepner's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48613456/1899640)

Answer (score 0):

You always need to put the (env) variable settings at the beginning of the command, i.e. before "daemon".